# Server on node.js + android client + json file

Tags: java, android, node.js, сервер, client

Есть RESTful API на Node.js который работает с json файлом.
Суть проблемы в том, что не выходит написать простейший android клиент(ранее с джавой не работал и в андроид студии впервые), который бы мог работать с api моего сервера, а точнее менять этот самый json файл:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Tom","password":24},{"id":2,"name":"Bob","password":27},{"id":3,"name":"Alice","password":"23"}].
```

Читал и про gson и valley и httpurlconnection, но в итоге не получается даже просто подключиться к серверу, нет понимая того, как это правильно делать.

Прошу помочь с написанием кода, ссылками на полезные статьи или просто советом.

P.s. Опыт сервер-клиент есть только из Qt, там с сокетами как-то попроще было....

Comment: У вас не получается отправить запрос на сервер или только изменить файл на сервере ?

Comment: Ни то, ни другое. Даже не представляю что после указания строки с url делать.